# how open front camera in android java

Tags: java, android, camera, photo

I want to open front camera, this code open camera but not front:

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePicture.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 1);
```

Comment: That is an undocumented `Intent` extra AFAICT. There is no requirement for any camera app to support it. If you need this degree of control over the camera, you will need to implement the camera UI yourself, using something like CameraX.

Answer (score 2):

This code is for launching the camera application and capturing an image, but it's not guaranteed that it will always open the front camera. The line

```java
takePicture.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

is an attempt to specify that the front camera should be used, but not all camera applications support this extra. To ensure that the front camera is opened, you need to handle the camera access in your own code using the Android Camera API.

I'll share an example right below:

```java
    private Camera camera;
    private int cameraId = 0;
    public void openFrontCamera() {
    
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }    
    camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
```